# ADFS SSO with custom Login form using php

Tags: php, single-sign-on, adfs

My actual requirement is i have 2 AWS servers on both server I have added xml file, my requirement is I want to login from our application page using email and password, this credential check in active directory is this user exists if yes it should return to my application with user details like email id, I want to implement this in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS supports WS-Fed, SAML 2.0 and OpenId Connect so you need a PHP client-side stack for one of these.

ADFS sits on top of AD so it will check the user in AD.

You have to use the ADFS login screen. There is no way to use a custom one.

Comment: Thanks for reply, can you please share the php code, how to achieve this Goal, please help.

Comment: For SAML: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43

Comment: For OIDC: https://jwt.io/libraries for the tokens or https://openid.net/developers/certified/